# Get dynamically value from data attribute

Tags: javascript, forms, mustache

How do I get and store the value of the `data-id` attribute? The value inside of it changes on button click, so I need a method that gets the value as it changes. I've tried document.getelementbyid/name/value but I get the only get the value stored from the first button click. The method I'm using now `$(this).data('id')` returns nothing. Thanks

mustache file:

```
<td>
    <form id="Form" action="./downloaddoc" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="p" value="download"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="fileid" data-id="{{file_id}}"/>
        <input class="button download_button" type="submit" value="Download">
    </form>
</td>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.download_button', download_doc);
function download_doc(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(id);
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '?p=download&id=' + fileid;
}
```

Comment: I do not see where the attribute value is updated on click.

Comment: it will work only if you are updating your attribute with same method, like $(element).data('id', value), it wont work if you do this $(element).attr('data-id', value)

Comment: edited my title because i see where it might be confusing. i have multiple buttons with unique data-id's , however when i click on one button and then click on another, the second button will return the data-id of the first. thats my issue @AvcS

Comment: Please post a [mcve] which demonstrates the issue. Maybe take your code and turn it into a runnable snippet.

Comment: this in your method represents the button not the input field

Comment: how do i get it to represent the input field? @AvcS

Comment: $(this).prev() will give you the reference of your input in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching for data attribute in the download button and not in the input field where it is actually present.

Add a class/id to the input field so that you can find it.

When you click on the button find the closest form and then find the input field which contains file id and extract the file id from it.

```
<td>
  <form id="Form" action="./downloaddoc" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" value="download"/>
    <!-- Added  a class to the input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="field" class="input-download-file" data-id="{{file_id}}"/>
    <input class="button download_button" type="submit" value="Download">
  </form>
</td>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.download_button', download_doc);
function download_doc(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Find the closest form
  var form = $(this).closest('form');

  // Find the input field which constains the download file id
  var input = $(form).find(".input-download-file");

  // Get the file id
  var id = $(input).data('id');
  console.log(id);
  window.location.href = window.location.href + '?p=download&id=' + fileid;
}
```